# Activator.GetObject - Using the state parameter

Tags: .net, remoting, parameters, state, activator

In .NET Remoting, *Activator.GetObject* method has a *state* parameter. What is the purpose of this *state* param? Can I retrieve its value from server side?

mdsn didn't help much.

What I'd like to do:
*Client side:*
`ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpChannel(0));`
`object obj = Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyObj), "tcp://serverName:1234/RemoteObj", "myCustomData");`

*Server side:*
Get access to the "myCustomData" string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of this state field is but it appears to be a channel specific value that's not of use to your code.  In tracing through `Activator.GetObject` in Reflector you'll notice that it eventually gets passed to `IChannelSender.CreateMessageSink`.  The use of this data is implementation specific.

A quick search revealed only one implementor if `IChannelSender`: `CrossAppDomainChannel`.  In this particular implementation the state parameter is only used if it is of a particular type: `CrossAppDomainData`.  This is an internal class which is not accessible to your program and hence is of no use.